# React native android on Windows: Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am trying to run an app on an Android emulator. After following the instructions in the React Native docs for installing Android Studio and setting the environment variables, I can create the default project, AwesomeProject, with "npx react-native init" but I cannot run it.

Keep failing the task
`:app:generateDebugBuildConfig`

I found several posts about this but none of them with the exception
`Execution timed out`

** Update
Tried `./gradlew clean` & `react-native run-android --port=8082`

the error message:

```
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
adb.exe: failed to check server version: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
Unable to watch the file system for changes
net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Execution timed out
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.AbstractFileEventFunctions$NativeFileWatcher.startWatching0(Native Method)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.AbstractFileEventFunctions$NativeFileWatcher.startWatching(AbstractFileEventFunctions.java:198)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.WindowsFileEventFunctions$WindowsFileWatcher.startWatching(WindowsFileEventFunctions.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.registry.impl.HierarchicalFileWatcherUpdater.updateWatchedHierarchies(HierarchicalFileWatcherUpdater.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.registry.impl.HierarchicalFileWatcherUpdater.virtualFileSystemContentsChanged(HierarchicalFileWatcherUpdater.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.registry.impl.DefaultFileWatcherRegistry.virtualFileSystemContentsChanged(DefaultFileWatcherRegistry.java:147)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.lambda$updateNotifyingListeners$0(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.registry.SnapshotCollectingDiffListener.publishSnapshotDiff(SnapshotCollectingDiffListener.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.lambda$updateNotifyingListeners$1(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.lambda$withWatcherChangeErrorHandling$7(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:313)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.withWatcherChangeErrorHandling(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:320)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.withWatcherChangeErrorHandling(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:312)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.updateNotifyingListeners(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.AbstractVirtualFileSystem.lambda$store$1(AbstractVirtualFileSystem.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.VfsRootReference.update(VfsRootReference.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.AbstractVirtualFileSystem.store(AbstractVirtualFileSystem.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:156)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readLocation$6(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:171)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readSnapshotFromLocation$7(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:196)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess$StripedProducerGuard.guardByKey(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:219)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readSnapshotFromLocation$8(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:193)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readSnapshotFromLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readSnapshotFromLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:178)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.read(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$SnapshottingVisitor.visitCollection(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractOpaqueFileCollection.visitContents(AbstractOpaqueFileCollection.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.visitSingleFile(UnpackingVisitor.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileCollectionFactory$ResolvingFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultFileCollectionFactory.java:333)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.DefaultOutputSnapshotter$1.visitOutputProperty(DefaultOutputSnapshotter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.visitOutputs(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:339)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.DefaultOutputSnapshotter.snapshotOutputs(DefaultOutputSnapshotter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:160)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionStateOp$1(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:127)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionStateOp(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:126)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$execute$0(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:72)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:92)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$2.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:402)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:389)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:382)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:368)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
Gradle was unable to watch the file system for changes
net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Execution timed out
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.AbstractFileEventFunctions$NativeFileWatcher.startWatching0(Native Method)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.AbstractFileEventFunctions$NativeFileWatcher.startWatching(AbstractFileEventFunctions.java:198)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.WindowsFileEventFunctions$WindowsFileWatcher.startWatching(WindowsFileEventFunctions.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.registry.impl.HierarchicalFileWatcherUpdater.updateWatchedHierarchies(HierarchicalFileWatcherUpdater.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.registry.impl.HierarchicalFileWatcherUpdater.virtualFileSystemContentsChanged(HierarchicalFileWatcherUpdater.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.registry.impl.DefaultFileWatcherRegistry.virtualFileSystemContentsChanged(DefaultFileWatcherRegistry.java:147)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.lambda$updateNotifyingListeners$0(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.registry.SnapshotCollectingDiffListener.publishSnapshotDiff(SnapshotCollectingDiffListener.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.lambda$updateNotifyingListeners$1(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.lambda$withWatcherChangeErrorHandling$7(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:313)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.withWatcherChangeErrorHandling(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:320)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.withWatcherChangeErrorHandling(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:312)
        at org.gradle.internal.watch.vfs.impl.WatchingVirtualFileSystem.updateNotifyingListeners(WatchingVirtualFileSystem.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.AbstractVirtualFileSystem.lambda$store$1(AbstractVirtualFileSystem.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.VfsRootReference.update(VfsRootReference.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.AbstractVirtualFileSystem.store(AbstractVirtualFileSystem.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:156)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readLocation$6(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:171)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readSnapshotFromLocation$7(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:196)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess$StripedProducerGuard.guardByKey(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:219)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readSnapshotFromLocation$8(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:193)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readSnapshotFromLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readSnapshotFromLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:178)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.read(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$SnapshottingVisitor.visitCollection(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractOpaqueFileCollection.visitContents(AbstractOpaqueFileCollection.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.visitSingleFile(UnpackingVisitor.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileCollectionFactory$ResolvingFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultFileCollectionFactory.java:333)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.DefaultOutputSnapshotter$1.visitOutputProperty(DefaultOutputSnapshotter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.visitOutputs(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:339)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.DefaultOutputSnapshotter.snapshotOutputs(DefaultOutputSnapshotter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:160)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionStateOp$1(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:127)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionStateOp(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:126)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$execute$0(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:72)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:92)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$2.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)

        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caught exception: Execution timed out
Stopping file watching and invalidating VFS after an error happened

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Watcher did not terminate within 5 seconds

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Caught exception: Execution timed out
Stopping file watching and invalidating VFS after an error happened

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Watcher did not terminate within 5 seconds

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Any clue what's the problem or maybe solution?

*** Update
Here is some parts of the hs_err_pid .log

```
Event: 834.200 Thread 0x00000208caecf800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': java/io/WriterCustomizer> (0x00000000f6c00858) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u281\880\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 212]
Event: 834.201 Thread 0x00000208caecf800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': java/io/BufferedWriterCustomizer> (0x00000000f6c0c9a0) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u281\880\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 212]
Event: 839.256 Thread 0x00000208caecf800 Exception <a 'java/lang/IncompatibleClassChangeError': Found class java.lang.Object, but interface was expected> (0x00000000f6f6f850) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u281\880\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver
Event: 844.485 Thread 0x00000208caecf800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000208b79e2c5f to 0x00000208b79e4405
Event: 844.486 Thread 0x00000208caecf800 Exception <a 'net/rubygrapefruit/platform/NativeException': Execution timed out> (0x00000000f5674b38) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u281\880\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 737]
Event: 844.497 Thread 0x00000208cbe2b000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': <clinit>> (0x00000000f571a780) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u281\880\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 1615]
Event: 844.497 Thread 0x00000208cbe2b000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': <clinit>> (0x00000000f571c4e0) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u281\880\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 1615]
```

Comment: *** Update 
Here is the hs_err_pid .log
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log you sent `error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds` it's an error with the ADB emulator itself.

Launch the android emulator first: Android Studio -> 3 dots in the corner -> Virtual Device Manager -> Play button

Then, try to install the app again.

Comment: hi Lucas, thanks for the reply
I tried to launch the emulator, though "Could not start emulator within 30 seconds", the error message, does not show anymore, still fail at ":app:generateDebugBuildConfig: Execution timed out"

Comment: Try cleaning the build folder: cd into the android folder and then run ```./gradlew clean```

Comment: Tried it, still not working for me...

Comment: is your code available on github?

Comment: No github... but actually the  whole is React Native default project, downloaded that through `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` :)
I updated the log message in the post, maybe it would help

Comment: That's odd, specially for a brand new default project. As a last resort, try opening the android folder in Android Studio an give it a go from there.